# I want update HTML empID field when I select empName from SQL table

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server

I have a HTML form where the user can pick an employee name (empName) from an SQL table called employees. I then want the employee ID (empID) associated with the empName to print under the empID section - eventually I want this to populate an input field.

I have tried doing this via another php, but I suspect its not right as I am not submitting the data before I want it to be used.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbConnect.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="employees" method-"GET" action="">
        Employee name
        <select name="empName" id="empName" class="form-control">
            <option selected="selected">Select</option>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT empName FROM employees";
                $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query");
                while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo '<option value="'.$data['empName'].'">';
                echo $data['empName'];
                echo "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        Emp ID
        <?php
            $emp = $_GET['empName'];
            $sql = "SELECT empID FROM employees WHERE empName = $emp";
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query");
            while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $data['empID'];
            }
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

If I select Andrew from the empName, then I want it to echo the corresponding empID ie. 10000 under the emp ID heading.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8gBO.png)

Comment: Just to be clear, you want employee's id to show right after selecting the employee's name, or after submitting the form?

Comment: Sorry, I want it to update before submitting the form - I have added an image.

Comment: Then you will be using javascript for that, I suggest reading about the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event

Comment: Ok I'll have a look into the change event